# Was Misa accessible to Light in the finale in the way that this proposition assumes?

Tags: death-note

Finale spoiler

> There's [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_j58ZQSf1vA) (alternative [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tfy0pU94fLA)) that proposes how Light could have beaten Near. A critical element of the proposition is that Misa is accessible to Light, but was she? I seem to recall Misa was in the custody of the SPK up until some time just before Light et al are about to leave

Comment: What the guy proposes in the video is impossible though. Misa has given up ownership of her note and her memories long time ago to Mikami, so she can't write down the names.

Comment: @PeterRaeves Why exactly can't Misa write down the names? Not sure I understand the relevance of the hypotheses

Comment: Misa doesn't know of the existence of the Death Note. Nor does she have a Death Note in her possession, or do you mean Light would give her a sheet of paper and tell her to write the names down Mika would send her?

Comment: @PeterRaeves Um, yes? That was what the video suggested right?

Comment: N only released Misa the moment L (and Mikami) were about to leave for the warehouse they were going to meet and he placed her into an unknown hotel. How do you suggest Light gets a piece of the death note there?

Comment: @PeterRaeves Post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### She accessible, but not in the way the video assumes.

From the [wikia episode plots](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Death_Note_Episodes):

> **Malice:**
>
> Aizawa thinks to himself that the reason this is happening is so that Light can either be exposed or kill Near. As Light accepts, Near lays out some ground rules: all members of the Task Force must be present, as all members of the SPK and Mogi will be there while **Misa will go elsewhere.** Near then gives the meeting location: an abandoned warehouse he purchased known as the Yellow Box, and also forbids the Task Force from leaving the Death Note behind, thinking to himself that this is what Light would want.
>
> **1.28**:
>
> The day finally arrives, and as Stephen Gevanni is on his way, Near announces that **Misa has been moved to a luxury hotel**, essentially freeing her. After Light confirms this, he asks Near to contact Mogi, who is with Lidner on their way, as to unlock the Death Note from a secure safe, each member has to put in a pin number that only each of them know individually.

Misa at that moment is a normal civilian girl, and there was no way for Light to **safely** get [Teru Mikami (x-kira)](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Teru_Mikami) contact Misa in the *luxury hotel* **Near himself chose to placed her at** whithout Near knowing. We can safely assume Near has a bug/tracker on Misa's cell phone (or can get a copy of the data). Or Mikami. Even if Misa is completely cleared, there is no way Mikami is not completely under electronic surveillance by 1.28.

Having Mikami contact Misa would have the same effect as not having his name written on the notepad. Light had very few pieces of DN left, if any by that time. It would be hard to find a piece where all those names could've been written (specially foreign names, with all those scribbly letters). And even if Misa was to text the picture of the names back to Light in 1 hour, it would give Near that much time to check the tracers and shut Misa down before she can forward the picture.

But the real problem was not assuming that Near would not find the DN inside a bank, the video gets that wrong. The unraveling of Light's plan was when

> Mikami broke his character, took the initiative (instead of just doing mechanically what he had always done) and went to the bank **out of his schedule** to [kill Kiyomi](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Kiyomi_Takada). Nobody expected Mikami, a creature of absolute habit, to do something so spontaneous. Had he kept to his schedule, Near would not have found the DN in the bank.

**TL.DR:** He could have done that, but it would give away proof of his alter ego as Kira to Near all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Misa would have been released before the text would have arrived. This means that the piece of the death note should have bean hidden in a public area near the building she was being held up. It would have also needed to be in an area no one would take the piece.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Raeves

> What the guy proposes in the video is impossible though. Misa has given up ownership of her note and her memories long time ago to Mikami, so she can't write down the names.

BCLC

> PeterRaeves Why exactly can't Misa write down the names? Not sure I understand the relevance of the hypotheses

Peter Raeves

> Misa doesn't know of the existence of the Death Note. Nor does she have a Death Note in her possession, or do you mean Light would give her a sheet of paper and tell her to write the names down Mika would send her?

BCLC

> Um, yes? That was what the video suggested right?

Peter Raeves

> N only released Misa the moment L (and Mikami) were about to leave for the warehouse they were going to meet and he placed her into an unknown hotel. How do you suggest Light gets a piece of the death note there?